# Html placeholder color

Tags: html, css

`<input type="text" placeholder="First Name *" />`

How can I change the color of place holder differently like "First Name" in yellow and "*" in red.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Simply you can't. You must use additional html and javascript to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the `placeholder` but I don't think you can add two colors in one `placeholder`. First, add a class name of `input` to the `input element`. Then add this `css`,

```
.input::placeholder {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements such ***input*** do not support **:before** and **:after**. To make things even harder the placeholder selector and their pseudo-classes are not fully supported by all browsers.

```css
input {
  width: auto;
}


/* the negative of the input width */

input[required]+label {
  color: #1b1b1b;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: relative;
  left: -166px;
}

input[required]+label:after {
  content: ' *';
  color: red;
}


/* show the placeholder when input has no content */

input[required]:invalid+label {
  display: inline-block;
}


/* hide the placeholder when input has some text typed in it */

input[required]:valid+label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
  <label for="name">First Name</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I made a snippet. It needs some attention, at least in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You could use linear-gradient to do this, but this first approach wouldn't work with fluctuating length of placeholder text

```
input::placeholder {
   background: linear-gradient(to right, gray 5em, red 5em);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

If your input text is right aligned, this would work with different lengths of content

```
input {
   text-align: right;
}

input::placeholder {
   background: linear-gradient(to left, red 5px, gray 1em);
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```